# File not found errors building an RPM

Tags: python-2.7, centos6, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I recently inherited a build server that was running fine until last week and now I'm getting some "file not found" errors. I am using "rpmbuilder" as my non-root user. When I run my build command I get the following errors:

```
$ rpmbuild -bb -v rpmbuild/SPECS/mist.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.fUrkkG
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.edkQrN
Processing files: mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64
error: File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist
error: File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/config.pyc
error: File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/mist_db.sql
error: File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/.password_complexity.conf


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist
    File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/config.pyc
    File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/mist_db.sql
    File not found: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mist-2.0.2-1.x86_64/opt/mist/database/.password_complexity.conf
```

I used to get a ton of output under `%prep` but now there's nothing. I tried using `%setup` without `-q` and still get the same output.

As far as I can tell my source files are still where they should be:

```
[rpmbuilder@coams-db SOURCES]$ pwd
/home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/SOURCES
[rpmbuilder@coams-db SOURCES]$ ls -la
total 66124
drwxr-xr-x. 3 rpmbuilder rpmbuilder     4096 Jun 23 10:08 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 rpmbuilder rpmbuilder     4096 Feb 25  2016 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 8 rpmbuilder rpmbuilder     4096 Jun 23 10:08 mist-2.0.2
-rw-rw-r--. 1 rpmbuilder rpmbuilder 67681925 Jun 23 10:09 mist-2.0.2.tar.gz
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? Are there some nitpicky things I didn't know to check? Like I said I don't recall changing anything but who knows...

My spec file is below:

```
Name:   mist
Version: 2.0.2
Release: 1
Summary: <snip>

Group:  <snip>
License: GPL
URL: http://<snip>
Source0: mist-2.0.2.tar.gz
BuildArch: x86_64
BuildRoot: /home/rpmbuilder/rpmbuild/%{name}-%{version}

Requires(pre): shadow-utils

Requires: python, mysql-server, python-sqlalchemy, MySQL-python, python-requests, python-lxml, pytz, python-jsonschema

%description
Installs the MIST application.

%pre
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then
    getent group mist > /dev/null || groupadd -r mist
    getent passwd mist > /dev/null || useradd -r -g mist -d /opt/mist -c "MIST Console User" mist -p '<snip>'

   # echo "Starting Cron Setup........."

    #echo "Create temp file to hold cron currnet data"
    #%define tempFile `mktemp`

    #store temp file name
    #TEMP_FILE_NAME=%{tempFile}

    #echo "Storing crontab current data in temp file %{tempFile}"
    #CRON_OUT_FILE=`crontab -l > $TEMP_FILE_NAME`

    #echo "Add required cron detalis in cron temp file"
    #ADD_TO_CRON=`echo "#Schedule the following cron job to <snip>:" >> $TEMP_FILE_NAME`
    #Replace the http://servername.com/file.php with file path or link
    #ADD_TO_CRON=`echo "*/30 * * * * python /opt/mist/assets/pull_assets.py > /dev/null 2>&1" >> $TEMP_FILE_NAME`

    #echo "Storing temp cron to the crontab"
    #ADD_TEMP_TO_CRON=`crontab $TEMP_FILE_NAME`

    #echo "Remove %{tempFile} temp file"
    #rm -r -f $TEMP_FILE_NAME

    #get current crontab list for email
    #%define cornDataNow `crontab -l`

    #exit 0
fi

if [ $1 = 2 ]; then
    /sbin/service mist stop
    #cp -r /opt/mist/frontend/server/conf /opt
    #rm -rf /opt/mist/frontend/server/work
fi

%preun
if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
    /sbin/service mist stop
fi

%prep
%setup -q

%install
# rm -rf "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
echo $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/mist"
cp -R . "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/mist"
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/var/log/MIST"
exit 0

%files
%attr(750,mist,mist) /opt/mist
%attr(400,mist,mist) /opt/mist/database/config.pyc
%attr(640,mist,mist) /opt/mist/database/mist_db.sql
%attr(640,mist,mist) /opt/mist/database/.password_complexity.conf
#/opt/mist
%doc

%post
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then 
    mv /opt/mist/mist_base/mist /etc/init.d
    chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mist
    chkconfig mist on --level 345
    mv /opt/mist/database/my.cnf /etc
    /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G mist mysql
    /usr/sbin/setsebool allow_user_mysql_connect 1
    /bin/mkdir -p /var/log/MIST/frontend
    chown -R root.mist /var/log/MIST
    chmod -R 775 /var/log/MIST
fi

if [ $1 = 2 ]; then
    #cp -r /opt/conf /opt/mist/frontend/server
    #rm -r /opt/conf
    #rm /opt/mist/frontend/mist
    if [ -d /opt/mist/frontend ]; then
        rm -rf /opt/mist/frontend
    fi
    mv /opt/mist/mist_base/mist /etc/init.d
    rm /opt/mist/database/my.cnf
    /sbin/service mist start
fi

mv /opt/mist/mist_logging.py /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
chmod 644 /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mist_logging.py

%postun
if [ $1 = 0 ]; then
    /bin/rm -r /opt/mist
    chkconfig --del mist
    /bin/rm /etc/init.d/mist
    /bin/rm /etc/my.cnf
    /bin/rm /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mist_logging.py
    /bin/rm -r /var/log/MIST
    /usr/sbin/userdel --force mist 2> /dev/null; true
    /usr/sbin/groupdel mist
    /sbin/service mysqld stop
    /bin/rm -r /var/lib/mysql
    /bin/sed -i '/mistDB/d' /etc/hosts
    #/usr/bin/crontab -l | grep -v "#Schedule the following cron job to <snip>:" | /usr/bin/crontab -
    #/usr/bin/crontab -l | grep -v "python /opt/mist/assets/pull_assets.py" | /usr/bin/crontab -
fi

%changelog
```

Comment: Are the missing files exist in your tar?

Comment: I actually just installed rpmdevtools on another machine and ran the spec file against the same .tar.gz archive and it worked! Looking into maybe refreshing the tools on the original machine.

Comment: I seem to have run into the same issue. Works on a different machine. However reinstalling `rpm-build` did not seem to fix the problem. Did you have any luck getting it to work?

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I did. I noticed the version of rpm-build was older than what was the latest so I simply did a `yum update` and it worked for me.